# Bing Ads API / Suds Python deserialise parameter error

Tags: python, django, suds, bing-ads-api

I have some (working) Python 3.5.2 code to download a report from Bing Ads via their API which I'm attempting to put into a Django application.

When I run the code via the Django shell, after I call SubmitGenerateReport(ReportRequest=report_request) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleads\util.py", line 123, in PatchedHttpTransportSend
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 132, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 613, in send
    reply = self.options.transport.send(request)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\https.py", line 66, in send
    return HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\googleads\util.py", line 134, in PatchedHttpTransportSend
    raise suds.transport.TransportError(e.msg, e.code, e.fp)
suds.transport.TransportError: Internal Server Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\joe.heffer\PycharmProjects\wisepanda\report\models.py", line 401, in query
    report_submission = reporting_service_client.SubmitGenerateReport(ReportRequest=report_request)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bingads\service_client.py", line 269, in __call__
    raise ex
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bingads\service_client.py", line 261, in __call__
    response = self.service_client.soap_client.service.__getattr__(self.name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 581, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 619, in send
    description=tostr(e), original_soapenv=original_soapenv)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 670, in process_reply
    raise WebFault(fault, replyroot)
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v11:ReportRequest. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.AdCenter.Advertiser.Reporting.Api.DataContracts.Request.ReportRequest. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.'
```

I can't find a problem with my SOAP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v11" xmlns:ns1="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v11" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <tns:CustomerAccountId>135071005</tns:CustomerAccountId>
      <tns:CustomerId>257199989</tns:CustomerId>
      <tns:DeveloperToken>BBD37VB98</tns:DeveloperToken>
      <tns:Password>*************</tns:Password>
      <tns:UserName>joe_heffer_sbx</tns:UserName>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
         <ns1:ReportRequest xsi:type="ns1:KeywordPerformanceReportRequest">
            <ns1:ExcludeColumnHeaders>false</ns1:ExcludeColumnHeaders>
            <ns1:ExcludeReportFooter>true</ns1:ExcludeReportFooter>
            <ns1:ExcludeReportHeader>true</ns1:ExcludeReportHeader>
            <ns1:Format>Csv</ns1:Format>
            <ns1:Language>English</ns1:Language>
            <ns1:ReportName>Bing Report</ns1:ReportName>
            <ns1:ReturnOnlyCompleteData>false</ns1:ReturnOnlyCompleteData>
            <ns1:Aggregation>Daily</ns1:Aggregation>
            <ns1:Columns>
               <ns1:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>TimePeriod</ns1:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
               <ns1:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>Spend</ns1:KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
            </ns1:Columns>
            <ns1:Filter>
               <ns1:AdRelevance/>
               <ns1:ExpectedCtr/>
               <ns1:Keywords/>
               <ns1:LandingPageExperience/>
               <ns1:LanguageCode/>
               <ns1:QualityScore/>
            </ns1:Filter>
            <ns1:Scope/>
            <ns1:Sort/>
            <ns1:Time>
               <ns1:CustomDateRangeEnd>
                  <ns1:Day/>
                  <ns1:Month/>
                  <ns1:Year/>
               </ns1:CustomDateRangeEnd>
               <ns1:CustomDateRangeStart>
                  <ns1:Day/>
                  <ns1:Month/>
                  <ns1:Year/>
               </ns1:CustomDateRangeStart>
               <ns1:PredefinedTime>ThisYear</ns1:PredefinedTime>
            </ns1:Time>
         </ns1:ReportRequest>
      </ns1:SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I think the clue might be that I'm getting suds errors that mention Google (the Google API (which also uses suds) is also installed for this Django app.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my report request specified custom date range parameters and a predefined date range.

This was identified by a Microsoft techie on their forums:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9dc7be19-9ac7-4cba-8472-e79300cd6655/webfault-deserialize-parameter-in-python?forum=BingAds

The solution is this:

```
# Build report request
report_request = reporting_service_client.factory.create('KeywordPerformanceReportRequest')
# Time range
report_time = reporting_service_client.factory.create('ReportTime')
report_time.PredefinedTime = 'ThisYear'
del report_time.CustomDateRangeEnd
del report_time.CustomDateRangeStart
```